# What is an example of a syzygy in invariant theory or pre-abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, invariant-theory

I need an example involving the old invariant theory that pre-dated abstract algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of Kleinian singularities. Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $SU(2,{\bf C})$.

$G$ acts on ${\bf C}^2$  and for each $G$ corresponds a Klein singularity
$$ S=\frac {{\bf C}^2 } {G} $$

$$ S=\{ (x,y,z) \in {\bf C}^3 \ | \ R(x,y,z)=0 \} $$

One example is the group ${\mathcal C}_{n}$, the cyclic group.

You can realize it as matrices of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \omega^j & 0 \cr
              0  & \omega^{-j}  \end{pmatrix} $$
where $\omega $ is a primitive root of unity.
The invariant functions, are functions which satisfy $f(u,v)=f(au+bv, cu+dv)$

The following three functions are invariant $u^n$, $v^n$, $uv$. Set $x=u^n$, $y=v^n$ and $z=uv$.  Then they satisfy the follwoing syzygy
$$z^n=xy$$